# Using TCPIP Stream socket, Trying to have server written in Python read data from client written in Java

Tags: java, python

I have test code that creates a server in Python and tries to read a string from a client created in java. Both server and client throw a exception.

Server side:
When python tries to execute `print(s.recv(1024))`
it gives me a error saying

> OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was
>   disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a
>   datagram socket using a sendto

Client side:
On the client side(java) a exception gets thrown when it tries to execute `output.writeChars("back");`
Gives error saying

> Software software caused connection abort socket write error error
>   java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket
>   write error

Test code server

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
print
"Socket successfully created"

port = 12355
s.bind(('', port))

s.listen(5)
print
"socket is listening"

while True:
    print("waiting for connection")
    # Establish connection with client.
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print
    'Got connection from', addr

    CODE CRASHES HEAR
    print("trying to get data")
    print(s.recv(1024))
```

Test code client

```
Socket MyClient=null;
try {
    MyClient = new Socket("localhost", 12355);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
DataOutputStream output=null;
try {
   output = new DataOutputStream(MyClient.getOutputStream());
}
catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
try {
    code crashed hear
    output.writeChars("back");
} catch( Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: You should not use such tight try-catch block when you're essentially ignoring the exceptions, you should use a single try-catch block for your code unless you can actually handle the IO error (or want to transform it to a different exception). Also, please post the full exception stracktrace (use `e.printStackTrace()`). The `DataOutputStream` is unlikely to be what you should use: it uses a Java specific data serialization format (similar to XDR). And for readability: please follow Java conventions. fields and local variables start with lowercase, (so `myClient`, not `MyClient`).

Comment: On server side don't `recv` on **s** but on **c**.